# Problem with config Ingest RTMP to connect OBS to Restreamer: Could not access the specified channel or stream key

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, rtmp, obs

I want to use OBS to push a RTMP stream to Restreamer server. But I get error:

> Could not access the specified channel or stream key, please
> double-check your stream key. If it is correct, there may be a problem
> connecting to the server.

Here a my configs:

1. Using Docker container to install [Restreamer](https://datarhei.github.io/restreamer/) ( v0.6.8 )

```
sudo docker run -d --restart always \
     --name restreamer \
     -e "RS_USERNAME=admin" -e "RS_PASSWORD=test" -e "RS_TOKEN=test" \
     -p 8080:8080 -p 1935:1935/udp -p 1935:1935/tcp -v /mnt/restreamer/db:/restreamer/db \
     datarhei/restreamer:latest
```

2. Setup for OBS:

[image]

3. I get error :

[image]

Please help me resolve this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Stream Key` is confusing, please try this:

- Server: `rtmp://xxx/live`
- Stream Key: `external.stream?xxxx`

Generally the Server should only set to the tcUrl of RTMP, while the stream should be in the Stream Key.